# How to get number of customer and total amount for time range?

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to have the result of the table below, I have two tables, one for the **clients** and one for the **transactions** made by the clients.Someone can help me to achieve that!Thank's in advance
**here is what i want to return**

[image]

This the query i write to get the result.

```
 $customers_trans = DB::table('contacts as c')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('SUM(tr.final_total) AS total_customer'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(c.id) AS customercount'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(c.id) AS average')
        )
        ->whereBetween('tr.transaction_date', [$date_debut,  $date_fin])
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->join('transactions as tr', 'tr.contact_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: So basically you want to have: between any two dates/time total no of client/customer who made transactions, total value of transactions and average value of transaction per client/customer - is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i want  @Donkarnash

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have there? You need to provide information on the table structure and sample data before anyone can help.

Comment: @miken32 i don't get the result like in this image. The table  as an example is  the picture below, the structure of the tables, I didn't want to put that as it's a bit long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$customers_trans = DB::table('contacts as c')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('SUM(tr.final_total) AS total_customer'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS customer_count'),
        DB::raw('AVG(tr.final_total) AS average')
    )
    ->join('transactions as tr', 'tr.contact_id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->whereBetween('tr.transaction_date', [$date_debut,  $date_fin])
    ->groupByRaw('HOUR(tr.transaction_date)')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: I w'll try it and tell you the result @Hafez Divandari

Comment: i get  an error Call to undefined method  groupByRaw

Comment: @Moum which Laravel version you're using? try `groupBy(DB::raw('HOUR(tr.transaction_date)'))` instead.

Comment: i use version 6 of Laravel , ok thank you

Comment: It works very well, thank you very much for your help Hafez Divandari, you saved my time.

Comment: @Moum glad it helped, please don't forget to accept it as answer.